# Show Attribute Value in list.phtml

Tags: list, magento, attributes

I try to show an attribute value for each product on the product list.
I tried this one:

```
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('myAttribute')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```

It works fine in view.phtml but shows nothing in list.phtml. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

let's say you have created a enquire attribute. Then just load product with sku.

```
$_sku = 'some_value';
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$_sku);
```

then simple use this to get value.

```
$product->getEnquire();
```

Comment: so how exactly would i insert that into my php file?

Comment: Open your list.phtml file and apply the code in both grid and list view.

Comment: that's what i tried to do, but it won't recognize it as code but as a text

Comment: After the foreach get the sku using this $_product->getSku() and to print attribute value use this. <?php echo $product->getMyAttribute(); ?>

Comment: can you right in detail what you are doing. I just run my code and it is working perfectly at my end.

Comment: i putted this on top of my file: $_sku = 'some_value';
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$_sku);               then i putted that directly below the loop: $_product->getSku()                                                                                at last i used this to show it on the site: <?php echo $product->getMyAttribute(); ?>

Comment: who will change values?? How much you have experience in magento? you have put code at top and accessing sku value after foreach.  products are coming in foreach so you have to apply this code in both list view and grid view after foreach. $_sku = 'some_value'; and some value with actual sku which you will get using $_product->getSku(); then you have to use the actual code not getMyAttribute.

Comment: i see what you try to explain but i have no clue how to work with php. i need to get the attribute value of each product, meaning at the beginning of each loop, ill set MyVar = GetAttributeValue($_product). I'm really confused right now